# Python curses dilemma

Tags: python, ncurses, curses

I'm playing around a little with Python and curses.

When I run

```
import time
import curses

def main():
    curses.initscr()
    curses.cbreak()
    for i in range(3):
        time.sleep(1)
        curses.flash()
        pass
    print( "Hello World" )
    curses.endwin()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

if I wait all the way through, `curses.endwin()` gets called so everything works out fine.
However, if I cut it short with Ctrl-C, `curses.endwin()` never gets called so it screws up my terminal session.

What is the proper way to handle this situation? How can I make sure that no matter how I try to end/interrupt the program (e.g. Ctrl-C, Ctrl-Z), it doesn't mess up the terminal?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do this:

```
def main():
    curses.initscr()

    try:
        curses.cbreak()
        for i in range(3):
            time.sleep(1)
            curses.flash()
            pass
        print( "Hello World" )
    finally:
        curses.endwin()
```

Or more nicely, make a context wrapper:

```
class CursesWindow(object):
    def __enter__(self):
        curses.initscr()

    def __exit__(self):
        curses.endwin()

def main():
    with CursesWindow():
        curses.cbreak()
        for i in range(3):
            time.sleep(1)
            curses.flash()
            pass
        print( "Hello World" )
```

Answer (score 46):

I believe you are looking for curses.wrapper
See http://docs.python.org/dev/library/curses.html#curses.wrapper

It will do curses.cbreak(), curses.noecho() and curses_screen.keypad(1) on init and reverse them on exit, even if the exit was an exception.

Your program goes as a function to the wrapper, example:

```
def main(screen):
    """screen is a curses screen passed from the wrapper"""
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    curses.wrapper(main)
```

Answer (score 3):

My advice:  For testing purposes, call your script using a simple wrapper shell script; have the shell script perform a `reset` command to bring your terminal settings back into a usable state:

```
#!/bin/sh
eval "$@"
stty -sane
reset
```

... call that as `run.sh` and be happy.  This should run your command almost exactly as your shell would if you entered the arguments as a command (more exactly if you wrap the arguments in hard quotes).

To ensure that your program will leave the terminal in a robust state, in the the face of uncaught exceptions and abnormal terminations ... either use the `curses.wrapper()` method to call your top level entry point (probably `main()` or whatever `main_curses_ui()` you choose to implement) or wrap your code in your own sequence of `curses.*` methods to restore cursor visibility, restore "cbreak" (canonical/cooked input) mode, restore the normal "echo" settings and whatever else you may have mucked with.

You can also use the [Python: atexit Handlers](https://docs.python.org/2/library/atexit.html) to register all your clean-up actions.  But there might still be cases where your code doesn't get called --- some sorts of non-catchable signals and any situation where *os._exit()* is invoked.

My little shell script wrapper should be fairly robust even in those cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can:

- wrap your code in a `try`/`finally` block that calls `curses.endwin()`
- capture the interrupt signal specifically via the [`signal`](http://docs.python.org/library/signal.html) library
- use the [`atexit`](http://docs.python.org/library/atexit.html) library.

The first option is probably the simplest for a basic case (if you're not running much code).

The second option is the most specific, if you want to do something *special* for Ctrl+C.

The last option is the most robust if you always want to do certain shutdown actions, no matter how your program is ending.

Comment: Is `atexit` really more robust than `finally`?

Comment: @asmeurer It's more a matter of the `finally` version requires you to guarantee that all of your program code is within the `try` block. In, say, a multithreaded environment, that's not necessarily the case.

Answer (score -1):

You need to capture the signal and run `endwin()` during the capture.

For info on this, look at this SO answer: [How do I capture SIGINT in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112343/how-do-i-capture-sigint-in-python)