# How to suppress the Terminated message when python script receives a SIGTERM

Tags: python, shell, signals

Is it possible to suppress the "Terminated" message that is printed on stderr when the python interpreter receives a SIGTERM signal. I would like it to terminate silently.

I have tried using a different signal, such as SIGINT, but in this cases python prints out the running scripts Traceback and a "KeyboardInterrupt" message.

Comment: Have you looked at the `signals` module?

Comment: Yes, my solution was to install my own signal handler and exit from there. The shell no longer printed out the Terminated message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Terminated" is printed by your shell, consult the manual for your shell to find out how to disable it.
As for `SIGINT`, you can actually catch this! To avoid printing the Traceback, simply wrap your whole program in

```
try:
    do_stuff()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
```

or register a Signal handler, as shown here: [How do I capture SIGINT in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112343/how-do-i-capture-sigint-in-python)

Comment: Any idea how to stop bash from print out the Terminated message? A similar question on here states that it can't be done, the best you can do is redirect stderr to /dev/null which is not really a solution for me because I still need the stderr output.