# How to handle KeyboardInterrupt (Ctrl-c) nicely with pycurl?

Tags: python, curl, pycurl, twitter-streaming-api

I am writing a Python script using [`pycurl`](http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/) to consume [Twitter's Sreaming API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-api/methods). Here's a short snippet that does exactly that (simply put your Twitter login/password to test it):

```
import pycurl

user = 'USER'
password = 'PWD'

def handleData(data):
    print(data)

conn = pycurl.Curl()  
conn.setopt(pycurl.USERPWD, "%s:%s" % (user, password))  
conn.setopt(pycurl.URL, 'https://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/sample.json')  
conn.setopt(pycurl.WRITEFUNCTION, handleData)
conn.perform()
```

The problem is that because the script consumes a stream, `conn.perform()` never returns (or very rarely). Thus, I sometimes need to interrupt the script, and the `KeyboardInterrupt` is caught by the `perform()` method.

However, it does not handle it well, prints an ugly error, and raises a different exception.

```
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 6, in handleData
    def handleData(data):
KeyboardInterrupt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 12, in <module>
    conn.perform()
pycurl.error: (23, 'Failed writing body (0 != 2203)')
```

The [cURL FAQ](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/faq.html#How_do_I_stop_an_ongoing_transfe) says that to interrupt an ongoing transfer, one of the callback functions (in my case `handleData`) should return a special value. This is great, but the `KeyboardInterrupt` is not caught by any of the callback function!

How can I do this neatly?

EDIT: I know that you can catch exceptions, but pycurl still does some funny things:

If I do:

```
try:
    conn.perform()
except BaseException as e:
    print('We caught the exception')
    print(type(e))
```

I get:

```
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 6, in handleData
    def handleData(data):
KeyboardInterrupt
We caught the exception
<class 'pycurl.error'>
```

This means that internally, `pycurl` does some kind of catching, prints an ugly error message, and then raises a `pycurl.error`.

Comment: `KeyboardInterrupt` [is not a subclass of `Exception`, it's a subclass of `BaseException`](http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy) - however, that does not change the output. (Although yet another example of why catching `Exception` is a bad idea.)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I corrected my example. It does not change my question though.

Comment: You need conn.close() after conn.perform().

Comment: Have you tried just putting `except:` without any `BaseException`? Have you tried putting in `try .. except` in `handleData` function?

Answer (score 2):

You need to catch CTRL+C and process that signal
Original: [Example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112343/how-do-i-capture-sigint-in-python)
Original: [Example 2](http://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html#example)

---

**Example 1**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import signal
import sys
def signal_handler(signal, frame):
        print 'You pressed Ctrl+C!'
        sys.exit(0)
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
print 'Press Ctrl+C'
signal.pause()
```

---

**Example 2**

```
import signal, os

def handler(signum, frame):
    print 'Signal handler called with signal', signum
    raise IOError("Couldn't open device!")

# Set the signal handler and a 5-second alarm
signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, handler)
signal.alarm(5)

# This open() may hang indefinitely
fd = os.open('/dev/ttyS0', os.O_RDWR)

signal.alarm(0)          # Disable the alarm
```

---

And at least something is not working on that twitter link, see [here](https://dev.twitter.com/node/10390/backlinks)

- don't forget to put **conn.close()** after **conn.perform()**

And it's helpfull to have debug mode enabled when testing.

```
import pycurl

username = 'your_user_name'
password = 'your_password'

def body(buf):
    for item in buf.strip().split('\n'):
        if item.strip():
            print item

def test(debug_type, debug_msg):
    if len(debug_msg) < 300:
        print "debug(%d): %s" % (debug_type, debug_msg.strip())

conn = pycurl.Curl()  
conn.setopt(pycurl.USERNAME, username)
conn.setopt(pycurl.PASSWORD, password)
#conn.setopt(pycurl.SSL_VERIFYPEER, False)
conn.setopt(pycurl.FOLLOWLOCATION, True)
conn.setopt(pycurl.VERBOSE, True)
conn.setopt(pycurl.URL, 'https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/sample.json')  
conn.setopt(pycurl.DEBUGFUNCTION, test)
conn.setopt(pycurl.WRITEFUNCTION, body)
conn.perform()
conn.close()
```

---

**Just copy/paste working test Example**

```
➜  ~  hcat twitter.py 
import pycurl
import signal
import sys
from time import sleep

username = 'bubudee'
password = 'deebubu'

def body(buf):
    for item in buf.strip().split('\n'):
        if item.strip():
            print item

def test(debug_type, debug_msg):
    if len(debug_msg) < 300:
        print "debug(%d): %s" % (debug_type, debug_msg.strip())

def handle_ctrl_c(signal, frame):
    print "Got ctrl+c, going down!"
    sys.exit(0)
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handle_ctrl_c)

conn = pycurl.Curl()  
conn.setopt(pycurl.USERNAME, username)
conn.setopt(pycurl.PASSWORD, password)
#conn.setopt(pycurl.SSL_VERIFYPEER, False)
conn.setopt(pycurl.FOLLOWLOCATION, True)
conn.setopt(pycurl.VERBOSE, True)
conn.setopt(pycurl.URL, 'https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/sample.json')  
conn.setopt(pycurl.DEBUGFUNCTION, test)
conn.setopt(pycurl.WRITEFUNCTION, body)

conn.perform()

print "Who let the dogs out?:p"
sleep(10)

conn.close()

➜  ~  python twitter.py 
debug(0): About to connect() to stream.twitter.com port 443 (#0)
debug(0): Trying 199.16.156.110...
debug(0): Connected to stream.twitter.com (199.16.156.110) port 443 (#0)
debug(0): Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
debug(0): CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
debug(0): SSL connection using SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
debug(0): Server certificate:
debug(0): subject: CN=stream.twitter.com,OU=Twitter Security,O="Twitter, Inc.",L=San Francisco,ST=California,C=US
debug(0): start date: Oct 09 00:00:00 2013 GMT
debug(0): expire date: Dec 30 23:59:59 2016 GMT
debug(0): common name: stream.twitter.com
debug(0): issuer: CN=VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server CA - G3,OU=Terms of use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa (c)10,OU=VeriSign Trust Network,O="VeriSign, Inc.",C=US
debug(0): Server auth using Basic with user 'bubudee'
debug(2): GET /1.1/statuses/sample.json HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic YnVidWRlZTpkZWVidWJ1
User-Agent: PycURL/7.29.0
Host: stream.twitter.com
Accept: */*
debug(1): HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
debug(0): Authentication problem. Ignoring this.
debug(1): WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Firehose"
debug(1): Content-Type: text/html
debug(1): Cache-Control: must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store
debug(1): Content-Length: 1243
debug(1): Connection: close
debug(1): 
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Error 401 Unauthorized</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>HTTP ERROR: 401</h2>
<p>Problem accessing '/1.1/statuses/sample.json'. Reason:
<pre>    Unauthorized</pre>
</body>
</html>
debug(0): Closing connection 0
Who let the dogs out?:p
^CGot ctrl+c, going down!
```

Comment: Adding `close()` won't change the fact that an exception is raised inside `body()` when interrupted.

Comment: @Wookai, yes, you're right, need to catch CTRL+C signal and process it, added examples how to. Thank You.

Comment: Could you mix the two into an example that works with pycurl?

Comment: @Wookai, maybe i haven't a hanging conn.perform(), but i've read in [python doc](http://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html) "A handler for a particular signal, once set, remains installed until it is explicitly reset", need a link that perform a long returning content to test.

Comment: @Wookai, forget to mention, i've attached what you requested.

Comment: Great examples.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by catching the pycurl.error type. Ex:

```
try:
    conn.perform()
except pycurl.error, e:
    errorCode, errorText = e.args
    print 'We got an error. Code: %s, Text:%s'%(errorCode, errorText)
```

Comment: This is the same as the second thing I tried, which does not remove the KeyboardInterrupt print.