# Interrupting `while loop` with keyboard in Cython

Tags: c++, python, interrupt, cython, keyboard-events

I want to be able to interrupt a long function with cython, using the usual CTRL+C interrupt command.
My C++ long function is repeatedly called inside a while loop from Cython code, but I want to be able, during the loop, to send an "interrupt" and block the while loop.

The interrupt also should wait the longFunction() to finish, so that no data are lost or kept in unknown status.

This is one of my first implementation, which obviously doesn't work:

```
computed=0;

print "Computing long function..."
    while ( computed==0 ):
        try:
            computed = self.thisptr.aLongFunction()
        except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
            computed=1
            print '\n! Received keyboard interrupt.\n'
            break;
```

(p.s. `self.thisptr` is the pointer to the current class which implements `aLongFunction()` )

Comment: What you want to do is capture `SIGINT`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112343/how-do-i-capture-sigint-in-python

Comment: mmh, this solution doesn't work with my function...the loop doesn't stop

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
import signal

class Test():
    def __init__(self):
        self.loop_finished = False
        signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, self.abort_loop)

    def abort_loop(self, signal, frame):
        self.loop_finished = True

    def go(self):
        while not self.loop_finished:
            print "Calculating"

            # Do your calculations
            # Once calcations are done, set self.loop_finished to True

        print "Calculating over"

Test().go()
```

You can also use additional variables to keep track of whether the computation was manually aborted or not.

Comment: I'm having problem in setting attributes for my class, because my class is a cdef class (I'm using Cython) and when I set class attributes in __cinit__  I get that the attribute is read-only

Comment: I've done very little in Cython, I (perhaps foolishly) assumed it would work the same. Hopefully someone else can help you out.

Comment: A **hack** that *might* work is to set `loop_finished` to `[False]`, in `abort_loop` use `self.loop_finished[0] = True` and in the `while` check the truth value of `loop_finished[0]`. If cython's int are mutable you could simply increment the `loop_finished` by one instead of setting it to `True`.

Comment: why are you addressing `self.loop_finished[0]`? is not an array or list

Answer (score 0):

I am not a Python C-Api foo master, however this works, but maybe its not the best way:

```
cdef extern from "Python.h":
    int PyErr_CheckSignals()

def test_interrupt():
    cdef int i = 0
    while i < 9999999999 and not PyErr_CheckSignals():
        # do fancy stuff.
        i += 1
```

Of course that is not asynchronous which is maybe possible but I do not know and this breaks the loop for any signal, not just Ctrl+C. Also maybe its better to not check signals every loop iteration, at least if what is done is very cheap.

You could call `PyErr_Occurred`, etc. if `PyErr_CheckSignals` did not return `0` and see what kind of `Exception` got raised to go specifically for `KeybordInterrupt` or certain kill signals. (Anyway, check the python C-Api for details there...)

---

If you are calling a cython `cdef` function inside the while loop you may be able to achieve this also if you add `except *`:

```
cdef function(...) except *:
    pass
```

see also http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/language_basics.html#error-return-values

Comment: @linello, did you actually see this? I added the except * thing, which I think would be nicer, but I did not try it. I think such a method should work too, but only if its a Cython function maybe.