# How to create global error handler in a multi-threaded python applcation

Tags: python, multithreading, error-handling

I am developing a multi-threaded application in python. I have following scenario.

1. There are 2-3 producer threads which communicate with DB and get some data in large chunks and fill them up in a queue
2. There is an intermediate worker which breaks large chunks fetched by producer threads into smaller ones and fill them up in another queue.
3. There are 5 consumer threads which consume queue created by intermediate worker thread.
4. objects of data sources are accessed by producer threads through their API. these data sources are completely separate. So these producer understands only presence or absence of data which is supposed to be given out by data source object.
5. I create threads of these three types and i make main thread wait for completion of these threads by calling join() on them.

Now for such a setup I want a common error handler which senses failure of any thread, any exception and decides what to do. For e.g if I press ctrl+c after I start my application, main thread dies but producer, consumer threads continue to run. I would like that once ctrl+c is pressed entire application should shut down. Similarly if some DB error occurs in data source module, then producer thread should get notified of that.

This is what I have done so far:

I have created a class ThreadManager, it's object is passed to all threads. I have written an error handler method and passed it to `sys.excepthook`. This handler should catch exceptions, error and then it should call methods of ThreadManager class to control the running threads. Here is snippet:

```
class Producer(threading.Thread):
    ....
    def produce():
        data = dataSource.getData()

class DataSource:
    ....
    def getData():
        raise Exception("critical")

def customHandler(exceptionType, value, stackTrace):
     print "In custom handler"

sys.excepthook = customHandler
```

Now when a thread of producer class calls getData() of DataSource class, exception is thrown. But this exception is never caught by my customHandler method.

What am I missing? Also in such scenario what other strategy can I apply? Please help. Thank you for having enough patience to read all this :)

Comment: Have you tried [the context manager](http://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager) ? Just tell to catch the exception by customHandler in the context manager code.

Comment: See http://bugs.python.org/issue1230540

Comment: woah..didn't know that is a bug! Thanks for the info

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a decorator. In essence you are modifying your original function and putting in inside a try-except:

```
def exception_decorator(func):
    def _function(*args):
        try:
            result = func(*args)
        except:
            print('*** ESC default handler ***')
            os._exit(1)
        return result
    return _function
```

If your thread function is called myfunc, then you add the following line above your function definition

```
@exception_decorator
def myfunc():
    pass;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just catch "KeyboardInterrupt" when pressing Ctrl+C and do:

```
for thread in threading.enumerate():
    thread._Thread__stop()
    thread._Thread__delete()
while len(threading.enumerate()) > 1:
    time.sleep(1)
os._exit(0)
```

and have a flag in each threaded class which is self.alive
you could theoretically call thread.alive = False and have it stop gracefully?

```
for thread in threading.enumerate():
    thread.alive = False
    time.sleep(5) # Grace period
    thread._Thread__stop()
    thread._Thread__delete()
while len(threading.enumerate()) > 1:
    time.sleep(1)
os._exit(0)
```

example:

```
import os
from threading import *
from time import sleep

class worker(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        self.alive = True
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.start()
    def run(self):
        while self.alive:
            sleep(0.1)

runner = worker()

try:
    raw_input('Press ctrl+c!')
except:
    pass
for thread in enumerate():
    thread.alive = False
    sleep(1)
    try:
        thread._Thread__stop()
        thread._Thread__delete()
    except:
        pass
# There will always be 1 thread alive and that's the __main__ thread.
while len(enumerate()) > 1:
    sleep(1)
os._exit(0)
```

Try going about it by changing the internal system exception handler?

```
import sys
origExcepthook = sys.excepthook
def uberexcept(exctype, value, traceback):
    if exctype == KeyboardInterrupt:
        print "Gracefully shutting down all the threads"
        # enumerate() thingie here.
    else:
        origExcepthook(exctype, value, traceback)
sys.excepthook = uberexcept
```

Comment: yes, I can catch it as it gets generated in main thread and can also process them. What I am searching for is how to handle exceptions generated within producer, consumer threads which are not the main thread

Comment: You could create your own exception handle for KeyboardInterrupt that does the same job if you just want to terminate on Ctrl+C? In other words put the enumerate() part in your exception handle and gracefully put down all the threads.

Comment: no ctrl+c is actually out of question. because, this application is going to run as a cron job. so no human intervention. however, I must catch any and all errors/exceptions and terminate application accordingly. otherwise it will keep running and no one will be notified that it has stuck inside a dead loop

Comment: Roger that, could this be of help? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112343/how-do-i-capture-sigint-in-python

Comment: Can't you just have an error manager thread watching a queue for shutdown messages?

Comment: Try changing the exception handler (like shown in my latest edit)?
Other then these given examples i'm not sure you would be able to pull it off without wrapping your main function in lets say main() or wrap() and do a try: wrap() except: ... statement.

Comment: @martineau : I already have one. But the class DataSource is a common resource, object of which is instantiated from factory method of some different class. so it's really difficult to pass that common resource an instance of such error manager class. If all else fails I will do it anyways. But I am looking for some more automated way. Plus what I have done is a kind of structure more people are gonna add up to it. I want that least amount of such code should be kept, otherwise if some one forgets to pass instance of error manager and forgets to call it's methods, chaos will ensue

Comment: If the error manager was a singleton object -- which in Python might just mean it was implemented as a module rather than as a special class -- it seems like it would become unnecessary to pass an instance of that common resource around.