# How to end a python program while it is running?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I study python by myself. And i got a problem here.."The human player may also end the game by pressing the Control-D sequence at any time." How can i do this.what kind of function should i use?
Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You could try [`sys.exit()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exit):

```
import sys
...
sys.exit()
```

There is also a more standard `exit()` function (for which you don't need to import anything). However there is one notable difference between this and `sys.exit()` as noted in the documentation:

> Since [`exit()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/constants.html#exit) ultimately "only" raises an exception, it will only exit the process when called from the main thread, and the exception is not intercepted.

Comment: `sys.exit` also "only" raises an exception, as noted in its docstring: "Exit the interpreter by raising SystemExit(status)."

Comment: Note that the `exit()` function is designed for use from the shell, not from applications. In any code you are writing, you want `sys.exit()`.

Comment: I don't think this fully answers their question. Are they not asking how `sys.exit()` would be called when the user presses `ctrl+d`?

Answer (score 0):

The basic logic here is to handle SIGQUIT keyboard interrupt. There are many kind of interrupts, Ctrl+C (SIGINT), Ctrl+D (SIGQUIT), etc.  [This SOF thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112343/how-do-i-capture-sigint-in-python) discusses catching Ctrl+C signal in python. Based on the same lines, its not hard to catch Ctrl+D. This [python documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html) provides more insights.