# Keypress for Status update in Python

Tags: python

I have a python program running a resource-intensive simulation. I would like to have it capture a keypress (preferably any, but just space would work too) and report status when it does.

How should I go about doing this?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Thanks! It worked. If you post as answer I will accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You question doesn't provide too much details, so it's hard to give a detailed answer, but in general, I would use the [`signal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#module-signal) module to print the status.

BSD has `SIGINFO` (bound to `^T`) for exactly this purpose; Linux & Windows unfortunately don't implement this, so it's not very portable.
On Linux, but you can use `SIGUSR1`, you can't send this from the keyboard, but you can use `kill`.

You could also use `SIGINT` (`^C`) to print the status. This has the side-effect of no longer being able to quit the program with ^C, though.

Also see: [Can I make use of an interrupt to print a status while still continue process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18973238/can-i-make-use-of-an-interrupt-to-print-a-status-while-still-continue-process)