# How do I capture SIGINT in Python on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, signals

(Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112343/how-do-i-capture-sigint-in-python))

On UNIX under Python 2.7, at the Python prompt:

```
 >>> import signal
 >>> def handler(signal, frame):
 ...     print 'welcome to the handler'
 ...
 >>> signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handler)
 <built-in function default_int_handler>
```

I press ctrl-c

```
 >>> welcome to the handler

 >>>
```

On Windows:

```
 >>> import signal
 >>> def handler(signal, frame):
 ...     print 'welcome to the handler'
 ...
 >>> signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handler)
 <built-in function default_int_handler>
```

Upon pressing ctrl-c:

```
 >>>
 KeyboardInterrupt
 >>>
```

I can verify that `handler` is being installed Python-side as the handler for SIGINT (calling `signal.signal` a second timer returns my `handler`).  How can I capture SIGINT on Windows?

Comment: I have tested it on Windows Server 2008 R2 with Python 2.6.6 and code above works correctly. This problem must be only in 2.7 version.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After opening [the bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue18040) upstream the root cause of the problem was found and a patch was written.  This patch won't be going into the python 2.x series.

Comment: Since several other answers meanwhile reference this answer, I felt obliged to point out that this bug ended up being closed as not fixed.