# Cannot receive signal in python on windows

Tags: windows, python-2.7, signal-handling

On windows I am trying to send signal through python script and receiving it in another but in the receiving script my signal handler is not getting called.
Following are the scripts :
signal.py

```
import signal
import os
import sys
import subprocess
import time

p = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "a.py" ])
print "created process id :" ,p.pid
time.sleep(4)
os.kill(p.pid,signal.SIGBREAK)
err,out  = p.communicate()
print err
print out
```

a.py

```
import signal
import time
import os
def signalHandler ( signum , address ):
    print "IN signal handler"

print os.getpid();  
signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM,signalHandler)
signal.signal(signal.SIGABRT,signalHandler)
signal.signal(signal.SIGBREAK,signalHandler)
signal.signal(signal.SIGFPE,signalHandler)
signal.signal(signal.SIGILL,signalHandler)
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT,signalHandler)
signal.signal(signal.SIGSEGV,signalHandler)
signal.signal(signal.CTRL_C_EVENT,signalHandler)
print "Going in sleep a.py"
time.sleep(10)
```

I am executing signal.py, which calls a.py internally. Signal.py is sender and a.py is receiver. 
I have tried using other signals like SIGTERM,SIGABRT,SIGFPE but was not able to catch them in a.py.

Comment: I am experiencing the same thing. :<

Comment: Looks like the problem is fixed [(see capture sigint)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16686510/how-do-i-capture-sigint-in-python-on-windows) but not for 2.*