# Reset Python SIGINT to default signal handler

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, signals

Version info:

- OS: Windows 7
- Python version 3.3.5

Below is small piece of test code I was playing around. The aim was to ignore `CTRL-C` being pressed while certain code was being executed, after which the `CTRL-C` behaviour would be restored.

```
import signal 
import time

try:
    # marker 1
    print('No signal handler modifications yet')
    print('Sleeping...')
    time.sleep(10)

    # marker 2
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_IGN)
    print('Now ignoring CTRL-C')
    print('Sleeping...')
    time.sleep(10)

    # marker 3
    print('Returning control to default signal handler')
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)
    print('Sleeping...')
    time.sleep(10)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('Ha, you pressed CTRL-C!')
```

What I've observed while playing around with this:

- `CTRL-C` sent between **marker 1** and **marker 2** will be processed by the exception handler (as expected).
- `CTRL-C` sent between **marker 2** and **marker 3** is ignored (still, as expected)
- `CTRL-C` sent after **marker 3** is processed but will **not** jump to the exception handler. Instead, Python just **terminates immediately**.

Also, consider this:

```
>>>import signal

>>>signal.getsignal(signal.SIGINT)
<built-in function default_int_handler>

>>> signal.getsignal(signal.SIGINT) is signal.SIG_DFL
False

>>> signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)
<built-in function default_int_handler>

>>> signal.getsignal(signal.SIGINT) is signal.SIG_DFL
True
```

So initially, while the signal handler is considered the default signal handler, it seems to be a different handler than the one defined by `SIG_DFL`.

If anyone could shed some light on this, especially while the exception handler is ignored after restoring the signal handler to SIG_DFL.

Comment: There are issues with SIGINT on Windows, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16686510/how-do-i-capture-sigint-in-python-on-windows and http://bugs.python.org/issue18040

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Python installs its own `SIGINT` handler in order to raise `KeyboardInterrupt` exceptions. Setting the signal to `SIG_DFL` will not restore that handler, but the "standard" handler of the system itself (which terminates the interpreter).

You have to store the original handler and restore that handler when you're done:

```
original_sigint_handler = signal.getsignal(signal.SIGINT)

# Then, later...
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, original_sigint_handler)
```

As kindall rightfully says in comments, you can express this as a [context manager](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/contextlib.html):

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def sigint_ignored():
    original_sigint_handler = signal.getsignal(signal.SIGINT)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_IGN)
    try:
        print('Now ignoring CTRL-C')
        yield
    except:
        raise  # Exception is dropped if we don't reraise it.
    finally:
        print('Returning control to default signal handler')
        signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, original_sigint_handler)
```

You can use it like this:

```
# marker 1
print('No signal handler modifications yet')
print('Sleeping...')
time.sleep(10)

# marker 2
with sigint_ignored():
    print('Sleeping...')
    time.sleep(10)

# marker 3
print('Sleeping...')
time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: Note that the default handler is always available as `signal.default_int_handler`.

Comment: python bubbles the exception up if you omit the `except:` block in a `try/finally`

Comment: Also note that `signal.signal()` returns the previous signal handler, so calling `signal.getsignal()` separately is not necessary.

Comment: Good point @SimonG. Took me a few moment to understand that indeed `original_sigint_handler = signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_IGN)` will already do the trick

Comment: No hit :(. This part of the docs is pretty bad. https://docs.python.org/3/search.html?q=default_int_handler