# In Python why is `KeyboardInterrupt` preventing the pickling of this object?

Tags: python, pickle, keyboardinterrupt

I need a better method or I need to learn how to use the method
I'm using more correctly. Normally, when I press cntrl-c
my work gets pickled, but one time it did not.  The subsequent time that I tried to open the pickle I got a `ran out of input` error. I need to know why this happened so that it does not happen again.  As I'm running my code, every one hundred loops I will save the pickle and if I hit KeyboardInterrupt, theoretically my work is supposed to be pickled before the program stops. My hunch is that if I press `KeyboardInterrupt` while `pickle.dump(obj, temp)` is being executed then the file will overwrite the old file but as it's overwriting if the program is killed in the middle of the overwrite then the file will be sort of half-written.  What I also do not understand is that after I hit `KeyboardInterrupt` the program should execute the line `print("help me")` but it's not, at least on the sole occasion where I tried that.

```
import pickle

def save_pickle(obj, file):
    temp = open(file, "wb")
    ##i have a feeling that if i hit keyboard interrupt
    ##while the below line is being executed that it won't
    ## save the pickle properly
    pickle.dump(obj, temp)
    temp.close()

class help_me():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def func1(self):
        try:
            self.func2()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            pass
        print('help me')  # this line did not get activated
        save_pickle(obj, file)

    def func2(self):
        #this function will take several days
        for i in range(600_000):
            time.sleep(1)
            if i % 100 == 0:
                save_pickle(obj, file)
```

Comment: I mean, yes, if your program is terminated halfway through saving, then you don't save a complete object. And your `save_pickle` call is not within a `KeyboardInterrupt` catch block. It sounds like you already know what the problem is; what do you need from us?

Comment: What do you want to happen when you program receives SIGINT midway through writing the pickle file? Finish the current object or discard it?

Comment: @SilvioMayolo `save_pickle()` is called from `func2()`, and `func2()` is called within `try/except`. That should catch the interrupt and then it should continue at `print('help me')`

Comment: @Silvio, it sounds like I know what the problem is, but sounds can be deceiving.

Comment: @Brian - I want to finish saving the current object.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo, I though `save_pickle` would be within the `try/except` because if `func2` is within `try/except` and if `func2` calls `save_pickle` then `save_pickle` is within `func2`.  After all, if the program is not within the `try/except` then why would it stop on `cntrl-c`?

Comment: @bobsmith76 You probably want something like this: before the loop, register a temporary [signal handler](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1112343/11082165) for SIGINT that sets a "stop" flag instead of raising KeyboardInterrupt. In the loop, check for the stop flag, and break when it's set. After the loop, [reset the signal handler](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22916783/11082165)

Comment: @Brian61354270, you're assuming a level of expertise that I don't have. Could you write up an answer and explain your thoughts in more detail.

Comment: I don't see how you do anything, at all. Once you call `func2` your program is locked up for 600,000 seconds, or 10,000 minutes!

Comment: @OneMadGypsy Did you miss the `KeyboardInterrupt` part?

Comment: @OneMadGypsy, it's an outline of a program, not a real one.

Comment: @Brian61354270 - I didn't miss the "worst possible way to do this" part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, if you terminate your program with SIGINT (i.e. CTRL+C) mid-way through pickling an object to a file, you may end up with a partially written (corrupt) file.

To avoid this, you can customize how your program responds to SIGINT so that the critical parts don't stop abruptly.

Before the loop, register a temporary [signal handler](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1112343/11082165) for SIGINT that sets a "stop" flag instead of raising `KeyboardInterrupt`. In the loop, check for the stop flag, and break when it's set. After the loop, you can [reset the signal handler](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22916783/11082165) to whatever it was before the loop.

```
def func2(self):
    stop = False
  
    def handle_sigint(_sig, _frame)
        nonlocal stop
        print("setting stop flag")
        stop = True

    original_handler = signal.getsignal(signal.SIGINT)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handle_sigint)

    while not stop:
        time.sleep(1)
        save_pickle(obj, file)

    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, original_handler)
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I have a few comments on your code:

- In the function `save_pickle`, if any exception happens while executing `pickle.dump(obj, temp)` such as a `KeyboardInterrupt`, the `temp.close()` statement won't be executed. To prevent that, you can use a context manager.
- Declaring the `help_me` class does not follow Python's idioms. Lose the parentheses and use pascal case notation like `HelpMe`.
- Instead of `except: pass` in `func1` you should better use `contextlib.suppress(KeyboardInterrupt): ...`.
- The line with `print('help me')` statement should get executed unless you press `ctrl-c` more than once. If you want that to happen anyway, you can use a `finally` statement.
- You can also lose the `__init__` function since it doesn't do anything.

To wrap up, here's my correction of the code, with just a few modifications:

```
import pickle
import time

def save_pickle(obj, file_address):
    with open(file_address, "wb") as file_:
        pickle.dump(obj, file_)

class HelpMe:
    def func1(self):
        key_board_interrupt_happened = False
        try:
            self.func2()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            key_board_interrupt_happened = True
        finally:
            print('help me')
            if key_board_interrupt_happened:
                pass
                # You can do the final save of what is left here.

    def func2(self):
        for i in range(600_000):
            time.sleep(1)
            if i % 100 == 0:
                save_pickle(object(), "file_address")
```

Comment: If you want the final save to happen after any kind of exception, you can loose the ``except`` statement. A simple ``trt-finally`` will do.

Comment: About pascal_case notation, I never use capital letters in any code I write, that way I don't have to remember whether a word has capital letters or not.  This reduces complexity and makes things easier to remember.  The sooner people learn this simple fact, the better.