# Performing an action upon unexpected exit python

Tags: python, terminate

I was wandering if there was a way to perform an action before the program closes. I am running a program over a long time and I do want to be able to close it and have the data be saved in a text file or something but there is no way of me interfering with the `while True` loop I have running, and simply saving the data each loop would be highly ineffective.

So is there a way that I can save data, say a list, when I hit the `x` or destroy the program? I have been looking at the atexit module but have had no luck, except when I set the program to finish at a certain point.

```
def saveFile(list):
    print "Saving List"
    with open("file.txt", "a") as test_file:
        test_file.write(str(list[-1]))

atexit.register(saveFile(list))
```

That is my whole `atexit` part of the code and like I said, it runs fine when I set it to close through the `while loop`.

Is this possible, to save something when the application is terminated?

Comment: You should register a SIGINT handler: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1112343/624900

Comment: When a program is killed it has no way to do anything before it dies. Better you provide some user interface for regular termination

Comment: @MichaelButscher depends on the type of kill, SIGINT and SIGTERM can be captured, SIGKILL can't

Comment: @jterrace From the contents of the question I assumed he meant a  SIGKILL but I should have made it clearer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `atexit` usage is wrong. It expects a function and its arguments, but you're just calling your function right away and passing the result to `atexit.register()`. Try:

```
atexit.register(saveFile, list)
```

Be aware that this uses the `list` reference as it exists at the time you call `atexit.register()`, so if you assign to `list` afterwards, those changes will not be picked up. Modifying the list itself without reassigning should be fine, though.

Comment: It no longer calls the function upon exit. The program just closes. Nothing happens.

Comment: How are you stopping the program?

Comment: Just by hitting the `x` button on the command line window. Is there another way to do it from within the code?

Answer (score 4):

You could use the `handle_exit` context manager from this ActiveState recipe:

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577997-handle-exit-context-manager/

It handles `SystemExit`, `KeyboardInterrupt`, `SIGINT`, and `SIGTERM`, with a simple interface:

```
def cleanup():
    print 'do some cleanup here'

def main():
    print 'do something'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with handle_exit(cleanup):
        main()
```

There's nothing you can in reaction to a `SIGKILL`. It kills your process immediately, without any allowed cleanup.

Answer (score 2):

Catch the `SystemExit` exception at the top of your application, then rethrow it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a a couple of approaches to this.  As some have commented you could used signal handling ... your **[Ctrl]+[C]** from the terminal where this is running in the foreground is dispatching a ***SIGHUP*** signal to your process (from the terminal's drivers).

Another approach would be to use a non-blocking `os.read()` on *`sys.stdin.fileno`* such that you're polling your keyboard one during every loop to see if an "exit" keystroke or sequence has been entered.

A similarly non-blocking polling approach can be implemented using the *`select`* module's functionality.  I've see that used with the *`termios`* and *`tty`* modules.  (Seems inelegant that it needs all those to save, set changes to, and restore the terminal settings, and I've also seen some examples using *`os`* and *`fcntl`*; and I'm not sure when or why one would prefer one over the other if `os.isatty(sys.stdin.fileno())`).

Yet another approach would be to use the **`curses`** module with `window.nodelay()` or `window.timeout()` to set your desired input behavior and then either `window.getch()` or `window.getkey()` to poll for any input.