# When cancelling a Python script do something

Tags: python

When i press CTRL+C to cancel a running python script, is there a way to run a certain python code before the script terminates?

Comment: You can catch the `KeyboardInterrupt` error; or you can set up [a signal handler](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1112350/344643); or you can do something at exit time [using the atexit module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/atexit.html#atexit-example).

Answer (score 6):

Use [`try/except`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement) to capture for [`KeyboardInterrupt`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.KeyboardInterrupt), which is raised when you press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Here is a basic script to demonstrate:

```
try:
    # Main code
    while True:
        print 'hi!'
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    # Cleanup/exiting code
    print 'done!'
```

This will continually print `'hi!'` until you press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.  Then, it prints `'done!'` and exits.

Answer (score 1):

CTRL+C raises `KeyboardInterrupt`.  You can catch it just like any other exception:

```
try:
    main()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    cleanup()
```

If you really don't like that, you can also use `atexit.register` to register cleanup actions to run (provided that you don't do something really nasty and cause the interpreter to exit in a funky way)

Comment: `atexit.register` is an excellent alternative.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you just need a `try/finally` block.

Try out this script:

```
import time

def main():
    try:
        while True:
            print("blah blah")
            time.sleep(5)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("caught CTRL-C")
    finally:
        print("do cleanup")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output should be something like:

```
blah blah
caught CTRL-C
do cleanup
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
    # something
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    # your code after ctrl+c
```

Answer (score 0):

This code

```
import time 

try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(2)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print "Any clean"
```

gives

```
deck@crunch ~/tmp $ python test.py 
^CAny clean
```

when I press `Ctrl+C` when executing.
You just have to handle [KeyboardInterrupt](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.KeyboardInterrupt) exception.

Also you can deal with [signals](http://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html) to set handlers.