# Killing a program with except: pass

Tags: python, hadoop

Is there any way to kill a program that ignores all exceptions? Stupid, I know. I was testing something (since I wasn't sure what error a failed, embedded pig script would throw), forgot to limit the loop to a single day, and now it's just continuously running even though I used

```
ps -ef
```

to find and directly kill it. I would just let it run to completion since it will definitely terminate, but it runs hadoop jobs, and is needlessly using up resources/popping up on the terminal in between other tasks randomly. I'd like to avoid shutting my desktop down since I'm running other tasks, but will if it'll kill it...

I got the pid from 
    ps -ef 
and used 
    kill -9 
to directly kill it. It no longer shows up when I run 
    ps -ef | grep  
but when I leave my terminal sitting for a little bit (even a new window) these "ghost" hadoop jobs show up that correspond to where the killed task would be.

Comment: `kill -9 <pid>` should take care of it.

Comment: Just to add some info, since we're talking about exceptions, if your code uses `except Exception:`, then `BaseException` won't be catched. Otherwise, the single `except:` statement will catch everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally your Python program would need registered listeners to handle any kill signal you send it. See here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1112350/276949

There is a special kill signal (`SIGKILL`, denoted by`-9`) which will kill your process no matter what.

```
kill -9 <pid>
```

Comment: The kill-with-no-exceptions signal is called `SIGKILL`, not `-9`.

Comment: Huh. So if I ran that command to kill it, and it no longer shows up, does that mean the random hadoop jobs are coming from somewhere else?

Comment: @user2958714 If the hadoop jobs got launched as sub-processes of the Python script, they'd keep running even after you killed the parent. You'd need to find the hadoop job processes and kill those, too.

Comment: @user2958714 http://linuxg.net/what-are-zombie-and-orphan-processes-and-how-to-kill-them/ - look for "How to find orphaned processes"