# Python: interrupt s.accept()

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
host, port = sys.argv[1:3]
port=int(port)
s = socket.socket()
s.bind((host,port))
s.listen(5)
while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    threading.Thread(target=handle,args=(conn,)).start()
```

I need to stop my code using Ctrl-C, but Python doesn't receive Ctrl-C when it waits for new connection (`s.accept()`). How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You should check out this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112343/how-do-i-capture-sigint-in-python). It details how to capture and handle the SIGINT signal.

Answer (score 1):

In order to stop the socket connection, you can call the `shutdown` method like so:

```
s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
```

(This SHUT_WR stops all new writes and reads)

However, while your code is running, it is suspended while trying to make the TCP connection. In order to stop it via Ctrl-C, you'll need to run the socket on another thread, giving your main thread the ability to wake up to the interrupt and send the shutdown message.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `shutdown()` or `close()` for your need

A wonderful explanation (from [*AIX 4.3 Communications Programming Concepts*](http://ps-2.kev009.com/tl/techlib/manuals/adoclib/aixprggd/progcomc/sktshutd.htm)) is given below

> Once a socket is no longer required, the calling program can discard the socket by applying a close subroutine to the socket descriptor. If a reliable delivery socket has data associated with it when a close takes place, the system continues to attempt data transfer. However, if the data is still undelivered, the system discards the data. Should the application program have no use for any pending data, it can use the shutdown subroutine on the socket prior to closing it.

Comment: yep i found it from there ..:) thats why i put it shaded

Comment: See [*How to reference material written by others*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing).

Comment: No, I don't want to close socket. I need to stop executing `s.accept()` by Ctrl-C at the moment I've already called `s.accept()`