# Close the program using keyboard interrupt in python

Tags: python

I am working on Python 2.7 on windows.

How to close the program by keyboard interrupt in python.

I made some code but it asks me every time to give a input and then perform something according to that. 
I want that the code should not ask me every time and at any random time when I give the input it should perform the corresponding action
(for my case close the program)

```
while 1:
var = raw_input("enter a to stop:  ")
     if var == 'a':
       break

exit()
```

Answer (score 3):

If you do not want to use the try-except construction, use can use the module [`signal`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/signal.html) to catch the SIGINT. The following code is from [this page](https://keyboardinterrupt.org/catching-a-keyboardinterrupt-signal/), where you can find a longer explanation:

```
import signal

def keyboardInterruptHandler(signal, frame):
    print("KeyboardInterrupt (ID: {}) has been caught. Cleaning up...".format(signal))
    exit(0)

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, keyboardInterruptHandler)

while True:
    pass
```

Ỳou can also check the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112343/how-do-i-capture-sigint-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

You can put your code in a try except block and catch keyboardInterrupt

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
try:
     # Do something here and when you key board interrupt 
     # The except block will capture the keyboard interrupt and exit

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    sys.exit()
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
try:
   while 1:
    var = raw_input("enter a to stop:  ")
    if var == 'a':
       break
except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
    print 'program stopped manually'
    raise
except:
    # report error and proceed,
```