# Python hide ^C from sigint

Tags: python-2.7

I'm catching ctrl-c with a signal handler and was wondering if there is a nicer way to hide the ^C that is printed to terminal than go os.system("\b") or similar. I only really care about Unix.

```
    def read(self, time_s):

        setup = ['Sensor', 'sensors', '\x00']

        # Closure for signal handler to allow access to self
        def sigintHandler(*args):
            self.close()
            sys.stdout.write('\b\b\r')  # Current solution
            sys.stdout.flush()
            sys.exit(0)

        signal.signal(signal.SIGINT,sigintHandler)
```

### Edit

My current solution is above

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112343/how-do-i-capture-sigint-in-python

Comment: I cant find anything there that stops the print? Or is that the answer which overwrites __exit__ and stuff?

Comment: That is for overriding what ctrl-c does. Are you looking to "silence" ctrl-c and keep it's functionality?

Comment: yeah basically still function the same but stop it printing ^C

Comment: chris is looking alternative to hide ```^C``` text printed when ```KeyboardInterrupt``` occurs

Comment: The terminal prints it way before it reaches Python.  I don't think there is a more viable Python solution to this.

Answer (score 2):

Using `print('\b\b\r')` will clear the annoying `^C` from the output.