# CherryPy waits for extra thread to end that is stopped later

Tags: python, multithreading, cherrypy

I am building a application that uses CherryPy to serve a REST API, and another thread that does background work (in fact, it reads data from a serial port).

```
import cherrypy
import threading

class main:
    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        return "Hello World."

def run():
   while running == True:
       # read data from serial port and store in a variable

running = True
t = threading.Thread(target = run)
t.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cherrypy.quickstart(main())

running = False
```

Both `api.pc_main()` and `run` work fine. The trouble is, I use a `running` boolean to stop my thread, but that piece of code is never reached, because CherryPy waits for that thread to finish when I push Ctrl-C. I actually have to use `kill -9` to stop the process.

Comment: global variables are always a bad idea because of such cases

Comment: @AzatIbrakov that is just to make the example. The actual code uses a class that has the `running` boolean.

Comment: it doesn't change anything, you just moving variable from global scope to class scope

Comment: @AzatIbrakov well, it does change something. It isn't global anymore. Not to mention, it is not the point of my question.

Comment: is there any way to work without threads?

Comment: @AzatIbrakov no. The serial port will have a continuous stream of data coming, that I need to read.

Comment: can you use `Python 3` instead? it has a nice `asyncio` lib for solving such problems

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142968/discussion-between-bart-friederichs-and-azat-ibrakov).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it by making my thread a CherryPy plugin. I used the code found here: [Why is CTRL-C not captured and signal_handler called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29238079/why-is-ctrl-c-not-captured-and-signal-handler-called)

```
from cherrypy.process.plugins import SimplePlugin

class myplugin(SimplePlugin):
    running = False
    thread = None

    def __init__(self, bus):
        SimplePlugin.__init__(self, bus)

    def start(self):
        print "Starting thread."
        self.running = True
        if not self.thread:
            self.thread = threading.Thread(target = self.run)
            self.thread.start()

    def stop(self):
        print "Stopping thread."
        self.running = False

        if self.thread:
            self.thread.join()
            self.thread = None


    def run(self):
        while self.running == True:
            print "Thread runs."
            time.sleep(1)
```

then in the main script:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    mythread(cherrypy.engine).subscribe()
    cherrypy.quickstart(main())
```