# Cherrypy - Run function to clean up environmen on shutdown

Tags: cherrypy, shutdown

I am using Cherrypy framework for some simple REST based apps. IF the server is being closed down, either by the operator or by the OS, I want to be able to run a function to clean up the environmental setup for that session. In many cases you can do this on startup, by in this case there is hardware that I want to close down.

In the documentation I could not find anyway to catch a signal that the server is closing down and run some code

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read the [help/on-topic], [mcve].

Comment: as mentioned by someone below, this can be easily done through a custom plugin. Write one and post if any help is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I have just stumbled into a similar problem and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29254591/4511441) SO answer, together with the [CherryPy docs on Plugins](https://docs.cherrypy.org/en/latest/extend.html#plugins) took me in the right direction: you should write a Plugin, very similar to the example in the docs, and then subscribe the Plugin registering it to the bus before starting the server engine.

*Disclaimer:* I'm pretty new to CherryPy, so my terminology might be inappropriate or even wrong.