# If starting unix pipe with Parallel command, pipe commands complain after cntrl-c

Tags: python, unix, joblib

If I start a process in parallel with joblib that calls a subprocess with a unix pipe (`sed | uniq | blabla`) many of those processes write error messages to the terminal after having sucessfully exited the python process with Ctrl-C.

```
sed: couldn't write 13 items to stdout: Broken pipe
uniq: write error: Broken pipe
uniq: write error: Broken pipe
sed: couldn't flush stdout: Broken pipe
sed: couldn't flush stdout: Broken pipe
sed: couldn't write 1 item to stdout: Broken pipe
```

Is there any way to avoid output like the above using joblib Parallel?

Comment: ctrl+c is  used to kill a process whether it is complete or in-process.By using ctrl+c you terminate the program therefore you get Broken pipe message.

Comment: How do I avoid this? Thanks for the info btw

Comment: Can you add the code you are writing in the terminal ?It might be helpful for better understanding.

Comment: Try closing `sys.stdin` in the python process.

Comment: @TheUnfunCat To control the behaviour of your program when you press CTRL+C, this answer may help you : http://stackoverflow.com/a/1112363/740316

Comment: Are those handlers sent down to the started parallel processes? I doubt it...