# nosetests: Getting a stack trace on Ctrl+C

Tags: python, stack-trace, nose, python-unittest, nosetests

With the code

```
import unittest
import time

class SleepingTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_that_gets_stuck(self):
        for a in xrange(100000000000000000):
            pass
```

I get this output

```
❯ nosetests use_nosetest.py
^C
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 4.267s

OK
```

As you can see, I did Ctrl+C to interrupt the program. But nose says it ran the test OK. I was rather hoping for it to say that the test fails **and give me a stack trace**.

Is there any way I can have a stack trace printed from where my tests get stuck?

Comment: There is nothing in your test case that fails. In order to get a stack trace, some condition needs to go wrong somewhere between the time your test is started and the moment you Ctrl+C.

Comment: @ILostMySpoon, ok. How do a python developer then debug why his/her program hangs in a unittest?

Answer (score 0):

Try [capturing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112343/how-do-i-capture-sigint-in-python) your Ctrl-C signal to prompt into debugger, i.e.:

```
import unittest
import time

from nose.tools import set_trace

class SleepingTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_that_gets_stuck(self):
        try:
            for a in xrange(10000000):
                time.sleep(1)
        except KeyboardInterrupt, err:
            set_trace()
```