# Prevent curses from using ctrl + c

Tags: python, cmd, python-curses

Curses keeps closing my program every time I do a CTRL + c, how do I prevent that from happening? I tried disabling the keypad, going into raw and noraw mode, but it keeps happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The program needs to handle the signal SIGINT. You can research Signal Handling in python and reference this related question: [How do I capture SIGINT in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112343/how-do-i-capture-sigint-in-python)