# SIGINT and exception handling in Python

Tags: python, signals

```
import signal
import sys
import time

def sigint_handler(signal, frame):
    print "signal"
    sys.exit(0)

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, sigint_handler)

while 1:
    try:
        print "text"
        time.sleep(2)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print "keybi"
        exit(0)
    except:
        print "except"
        continue
```

When I press <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> I see "signal" and "except" and the program doesn't exit.

1. Why doesn't the program exit, while it apparently reaches `sys.exit(0)`?
2. Why doesn't the program flow reach the `KeyboardInterrupt` section?
3. What is the concise way to make <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> work and handle each `except:` case separately in different places without exiting?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I capture SIGINT in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112343/how-do-i-capture-sigint-in-python)

Comment: Duplicate doesn't answer 1, which is answered below

Answer (score 11):

The program doesn't exit because `sys.exit` works by throwing a `SystemExit` exception, and your blanket `except` caught it.

The `except KeyboardInterrupt` doesn't fire because the `SIGINT` handler you installed overrides the default `SIGINT` handler, and the default `SIGINT` handler is responsible for raising a `KeyboardInterrupt` when you hit Ctrl-C.

As for your third question, it's unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

@user2357112 answered your first two questions, as to your third, you can create your own exception in the signal handler.  In this example we raise `MyError` in the event of a SIGINT.

```
import signal
import time

class MyError(Exception): 
    pass

def handler(sig, frame):
    raise MyError('Received signal ' + str(sig) +
                  ' on line ' + str(frame.f_lineno) +
                  ' in ' + frame.f_code.co_filename)    

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handler)

try:
    while 1:
        time.sleep(1)        # Hit <CTRL>+C here
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('Keyboard interrupt caught')
except MyError as err:
    print("Hiccup:",err)
    # do stuff

print('Clean exit')
```

If you comment out the call to `signal.signal()` then you will get a KeyboardInterrupt, as described.

Comment: And what if I want to do some action and then exit regardless of what "except" blocks are there?

Comment: Ah ok, I'll just re-raise KeyboardInterrupt.

Comment: Just call `sys.exit()` to exit.  That didn't work last time because you had a "catch-all" `except:`.    If you want to force an exit (which you should think carefully about before doing) then you can call `os._exit()`, but that can have strange side effects because clean-up code will not be executed.

Comment: By the way, `exit()` is meant only for interactive use, it shouldn't be used in scripts.  `exit` and `quit` are actually objects of `site.Quitter` class.  Quote from the python documentation "*They are useful for the interactive interpreter shell and should not be used in programs.*"  When called they raise a `SystemExit` exception and close `stdin` - IDLE ignores `SystemExit` but closes when stdin is closed. 
Quite apart from the fact that the `site` module might not be loaded, the side effect could upset code that traps the `SystemExit` exception yet still expects stdin to be there.