# Wait and complete processes when Python script is stopped from PyCharm console?

Tags: python, pycharm, exit

Basically I am writing a script that can be stopped and resumed at any time. So if the user uses, say `PyCharm console` to execute the program, he can just click on the stop button whenever he wants.

Now, I need to save some variables and let an ongoing function finish before terminating. What functions do I use for this?

I have already tried `atexit.register()` to no avail.
Also, how do I make sure that an ongoing function is completed before the program can exit?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it using a really bad workaround. I used all functions that are related to exit in Python, including SIG* functions, but uniquely, I did not find a way to catch the exit signal when Python program is being stopped by pressing the "Stop" button in PyCharm application. Finally got a workaround by using tkinter to open an empty window, with my program running in a background thread, and used that to close/stop program execution. Works wonderfully, and catches the SIG* signal as well as executing atexit . Anyways massive thanks to @scrineym as the link really gave a lot of useful information that did help me in development of the final version.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might want to catch a signal.

When a program is told to stop a signal is sent to the process from the OS, you can then catch them and do cleanup before exit. There are many diffferent signals , for xample when you press CTRL+C a SIGINT signal is sent by the OS to stop your process, but there are many others.

See here : [How do I capture SIGINT in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112343/how-do-i-capture-sigint-in-python)

and here for the signal library: https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html