# Is there a workaround for "try: input() except KeyboardInterrupt:"

Tags: python, powershell, windows-10, python-3.5, try-except

I've searched this topic to no avail for hours.

Is it possible to do something along the lines of:

```
try:
    input_var = input('> ')
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("This will not work.")
```

But when I try this and do CTRL-C, it just does nothing.

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Using Windows 10, Python 3.5.2, and Powershell

Note: I am not using the input_var for printing, I am doing 3 if/elif/else statements based around it.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you would be interested in the signal module.

[This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1112350/4171411) demonstrates how to use the signal module to capture Ctrl+C, or SIGINT.

For your use case, something along the lines of the following would work :

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
import signal

def signal_handler(signal, frame):
    raise KeyboardInterrupt('SIGINT received')

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
try :
    input_var = input('> ')
except KeyboardInterrupt :
    print("CTRL+C Pressed!")
```

Comment: Just tried it, it just returned this:                                             Traceback (most recent call last):

Comment: Looks like your comment was cut off; this works for me using python3. Keep in mind that if run using python2, raw_input() should be used in place of input()

Comment: I modified the answer to use python3 by default, I didn't catch that at the time of writing. You'll need to change the first line to match your python install location, or run the script as > python3 script.py

Comment: Im doing it exactly as you have said, still not doing a single thing...

Comment: I already said.  "Traceback (most recent call last): " its not getting cut off... It's not even an error.

Comment: Curious... Sadly I can't reproduce this on Windows / Powershell as I'm working on linux, but I'll do some digging.