# Cleanup if script is terminated e.g ctrl+c like Perl's END {}

Tags: python-3.x, pyro

Is there something like Perl's `END {}`-block in python? In Perl that block will execute if the script is being terminated somehow.

I found [atexit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/atexit.html#module-atexit) but it is not working with `ctrl+c`

I am playing around with Pyro4 and I want to put a `ns.unregister()` in that block.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I capture SIGINT in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112343/how-do-i-capture-sigint-in-python)

Comment: what about simply ``try..... catch KeyboardInterrupt:  ns=Pyro4.locateNS();  ns.unregister(...)`` ?

Comment: It is not limited to KeyboardInterrupt. That was only one scenario. But thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For my special purpose I found the NS_AUTOCLEAN flag [here](https://pythonhosted.org/Pyro4/nameserver.html)