# Capturing SIGINT using KeyboardInterrupt exception works in terminal, not in script

Tags: python, bash, shell, sigint

I'm trying to catch `SIGINT` (or keyboard interrupt) in Python 2.7 program. This is how my Python test script `test` looks:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import time

try:
    time.sleep(100)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
except:
    print "error"
```

Next I have a shell script `test.sh`:

```
./test & pid=$!
sleep 1
kill -s 2 $pid
```

When I run the script with bash, or sh, or something `bash test.sh`, the Python process `test` stays running and is not killable with `SIGINT`. Whereas when I copy `test.sh` command and paste it into (bash) terminal, the Python process `test` shuts down.

I cannot get what's going on, which I'd like to understand. So, where is difference, and why?

This is not about *how to catch `SIGINT` in Python!* According to [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html) – this is the way, which should work:

> Python installs a small number of signal handlers by default: SIGPIPE ... and SIGINT is translated into a KeyboardInterrupt exception

It is indeed catching `KeyboardInterrupt` when `SIGINT` is sent by `kill` if the program is started directly from shell, but when the program is started from bash script run on background, it seems that `KeyboardInterrupt` is never raised.

Comment: Excellent question, the first new thing that I learned about Python today.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There is one case in which the default sigint handler is *not* installed at startup, and that is when the signal mask contains `SIG_IGN` for `SIGINT` at program startup. The code responsible for this can be found [here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/6eefdf0fade6/Modules/signalmodule.c#l608).

The signal mask for ignored signals is inherited from the parent process, while handled signals are reset to `SIG_DFL`. So in case `SIGINT` was ignored the condition `if (Handlers[SIGINT].func == DefaultHandler)` in the source won't trigger and the default handler is not installed, python doesn't override the settings made by the parent process in this case.

So let's try to show the used signal handler in different situations:

```
# invocation from interactive shell
$ python -c "import signal; print(signal.getsignal(signal.SIGINT))"
<built-in function default_int_handler>

# background job in interactive shell
$ python -c "import signal; print(signal.getsignal(signal.SIGINT))" &
<built-in function default_int_handler>

# invocation in non interactive shell
$ sh -c 'python -c "import signal; print(signal.getsignal(signal.SIGINT))"'
<built-in function default_int_handler>

# background job in non-interactive shell
$ sh -c 'python -c "import signal; print(signal.getsignal(signal.SIGINT))" &'
1
```

So in the last example, `SIGINT` is set to 1 (`SIG_IGN`). This is the same as when you start a background job in a shell script, as those are non interactive by default (unless you use the `-i` option in the shebang).

So this is caused by the shell ignoring the signal when launching a background job in a non interactive shell session, not by python directly. At least `bash` and `dash` behave this way, I've not tried other shells.

There are two options to deal with this situation:

- manually install the default signal handler:

  ```
  import signal
  signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.default_int_handler)
  ```
- add the `-i` option to the shebang of the shell script, e.g:

  ```
  #!/bin/sh -i
  ```

---

edit: this behaviour is documented in the bash manual:

> SIGNALS
>   ...
>   When job control is not in effect, asynchronous commands ignore SIGINT and SIGQUIT in addition to these inherited handlers.

which applies to non-interactive shells as they have job control disabled by default, and is actually specified in POSIX: [Shell Command Language](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_11)

Comment: Thanks for nice explanation. Still, Python documentation is a bit misleading then, isn't it? I think it should state, that it's only adding SIGINT handler if it's not ignored in starting signal mask.

Comment: Yes, the documentation should probably mention that it doesn't set the sigint handler when it wasn't set to `SIG_DFL` at startup