# Why i can show the final value of variable?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I have this code that read the Raspberry Pi RPIO pin number 24, that is connected to coin acceptor and the datasheet of it is:

```
0,05€ - 1 pulse
0,10€ - 2 pulse each pulse in 0,025ms
0,20€ - 4 pulse each pulse in 0,025ms
0,50€ - 10 pulse each pulse in 0,025ms
1€    - 20 pulse each pulse in 0,025ms
2€    - 40 pulse each pulse in 0,025ms
```

And i have this code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(24,GPIO.IN)

count = 0
euroCoin = 0

def coin(value):
  euro = value * 5
  return euro

while True:
   inputValue = GPIO.input(24)
   if (inputValue == True):
    count = count + 1
    euroCount = coin(count)
    print ("Euro "+str(euroCount)+".")
   time.sleep(.025)
```

That show, for example, for 0,20€ coin show:

```
0,05
0,10
0,15
0,20
```

I only need to show the final value, how i do that?
Thanks

Comment: when does the loop *break*?

Comment: @JimFasarakis-Hilliard Looks like OP is triggering on a GPIO pin. Process can run forever

Comment: How does the hardware (or the user) tell you when what you've gotten is "final"?

Comment: @cricket_007 doesn't that contradict the concept of a "final" value?

Comment: @JimFasarakis-Hilliard I can't speak for what OP thinks the code should be doing

Answer (score 0):

If you're terminating the program with a signal, like CTRL-C (SIGINT), you'll need to write a handler to catch that signal. Otherwise, you can't capture the value you're after.

See [How do I capture SIGINT in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112343/how-do-i-capture-sigint-in-python)

Comment: I don't need to close the program, i need to show the final value that i put and await for more coins, did you understand me?

Comment: If you wait for more coins how do you know what the final value is?