# Killing python program in Windows gracefully

Tags: python, windows, sockets

I am running a Python script in Windows which is basically a simple UDP server. Most of the time the program will wait on `recv_data, addr = server_socket.recvfrom(2048)`. I have two issues:

1. I am not able to kill this program without closing the console. This is not a big issue as I can close the console and restart the program. But still...
2. Even when I close the console, most of the time, the socket is not getting closed properly. I could see the program in a killed state. So I have to change the port every time I restart. Even when I do not see the program in killed state and holding the socket, the server is not able to receive any packets. (And yes I am using `SO_REUSEADDR` for my server socket.)

Any ideas?

Comment: try the top answer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112343/how-do-i-capture-sigint-in-python)

Comment: `import sys sys.exit()`