# How can I capture CTRL+C and execute a condition inside my main function in python?

Tags: python, signals

I searched for answers relevant to this, but didn't come across any. I am writing a socket program for a P2P network for which I need to incorporate some signal handling.

If I press CTRL+C while I am running the program, the program should send a "LEAVE" request to another peer.

Pseudo code:

```
if conditionX
    dosomething(IP, port)
if conditionY
    dosomethingelse(IP, port)
if SIGINT detected
    sendleaverequest(peerip, port)
```

How can I implement signal handling here?

Answer (score 2):

CTRL-C is the one of the signal for operating system. You can handle signals in programming languages including signal libraries or modules.

For Python you can use system module, If you handle `signal.SIGINT`, you can execute your own code when you press  `CTRL-C`.

**Example Usage from the previous questions:**

Visit:
[How do I capture SIGINT in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112343/how-do-i-capture-sigint-in-python)