# Google cloud platform not recognizing instance in app.yaml

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to create a new environment on google cloud platform. It's not recognizing my instance class... and giving the error `Instance class (n1-standard-1) is not recognized`

```
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT presto.wsgi
env: flex
runtime: python
instance_class: n1-standard-1

runtime_config:
  python_version: 3
```

`n1-standard-1` is given from google's documentation so I'm not sure what's wrong here. Does it go by a different name? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the python flex environment, the [resource config](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#resource-settings) is defined in a different way.

To get the same machine as a [`n1-standard-1`](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types#standard_machine_types), you must add the following resource definition in your `app.yaml`:

```
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 3.75
```

Comment: Another slightly related question about app.yaml. Do you know how to add a python command to run upon end of deployment. similar to container command in aws?

Comment: You should capture `SIGINT`in your code. Here's an [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112343/how-do-i-capture-sigint-in-python) with more details. Be sure to finish quickly, as instances will be killed a few seconds after `SIGINT`. It might me worth it's specific SO question if you find trouble.