# ram memory consumed after program exit

Tags: python, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, terminal

I am running a python script on linux terminal. The script has an infinite calculus loop and it never ends, so for now I'm stopping it with ctrl+C. After that, all the ram memory consumed by the program (which is a lot, and I don't find the leakage yet) is still consumed, until the moment I close the terminal. What can be happening?

Comment: Does it spawn any subprocesses?  What program is identified as owning that memory?

Comment: Please post minimal verifiable complete example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using a combination of:
[How do I capture SIGINT in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112343/how-do-i-capture-sigint-in-python)
and
[How can I explicitly free memory in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316767/how-can-i-explicitly-free-memory-in-python)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import signal
import sys
import gc
def signal_handler(signal, frame):
        print('Cleaning up...')
        gc.collect()
        print('Bye.')
        sys.exit(0)
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
signal.pause()
```

Answer (score 0):

it may be an infinte loop or just some calculations that took too much time, for the sake of completeness, can you please post your code?