# Can't kill multiprocessing pool in a multithreaded C application embedding Python

Tags: python, c, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-c-api

OS: linux 
Python version: 3.6

I'm trying to extend a C application with Python runtime. The C application uses `pthread` and I tried to use `multiprocessing` `forkserver` in Python runtime but faced a problem. When I try to kill the program with `SIGINT` signal (by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in the terminal) the worker processes get killed but the main program hangs.

Here is a toy program that produces the same problem.

```c
#include <Python.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void * thread_start(void *unsed)
{
    PyObject *fs_mod = PyImport_AddModule("fs");
    PyObject *apply_fn = PyObject_GetAttrString(fs_mod, "apply");
    PyObject *job_fn = PyObject_GetAttrString(fs_mod, "job");
    PyObject *job_args = Py_BuildValue("()");
    PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs(apply_fn, job_fn, job_args, NULL);
    printf("finished\n");
    return NULL;
}

int main(){
    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString(
        "import sys; sys.path.append('...');"
        "sys.argv=['a.out'];"  // prepare a dummy argument to avoid error in forkserver
        "import fs\n"
        "if __name__ == '__main__': fs.init()");

    while(1){
        pthread_t thread;
        pthread_create(&thread, 0, &thread_start, NULL);
        printf("joing\n");
        pthread_join(thread, 0);
    }
}
```

```py
import multiprocessing as mp

pool = None


def job():
    import time
    print("running..")
    time.sleep(5)

def init():
    global pool
    mp.set_start_method('forkserver')
    pool = mp.Pool(1)

def apply(*args):
    global pool
    return pool.apply(*args)
```

I don't exactly know how Linux signal works. I tried to catch `SIGINT` signal in the main python process with signal module, but it seems that main it doesn't get to receive the signal. How would I be able to make this application die gracefully on `SIGINT` without hanging forever?

---

By reading ViKiG answer, I realized that I can first catch the `KeyboardInterrupt`(or `SIGINT`) exception in the worker processes and send some sentinel value to the main process to notify the exception and shut down the application.

After skimming through the CPython forkserver implementation, I potentially concluded that the author of the library intentionally made the main process ignore the `SIGINT`. I guess, currently, that the recommended way is to catch the exception in the worker processes, not in the main one.

Comment: I searched on [python tag and SIGINT to find this answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112343/how-do-i-capture-sigint-in-python).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I capture SIGINT in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112343/how-do-i-capture-sigint-in-python)

Comment: @jwdonahue I tried signal module but failed to catch the SIGINT signal. That’s why I mentioned that “the main process doesn’t get to receive SIGINT signal”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I don't have to catch the exception in the main process. I solved the problem by catching the `KeyboardInterrupt`(or `SIGINT`) exception in the worker processes and send some sentinel value to the main process to notify the exception and shut down the application.

```
import multiprocessing as mp


pool = None


def job():
    try:
        import time
        print("running..")
        time.sleep(5)
        return True
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Exiting..")
        return False
...

def apply(*args):
    global pool
    ret = pool.apply(*args)
    if ret:
        return pool.apply(*args)
    else:
        print("Gracefully die")
```

Answer (score 1):

`Py_Initialize()` will install python's own singal handler, call `Py_InitializeEx(0)` instead:

> void Py_InitializeEx(int initsigs)
>
> This function works like
>   Py_Initialize() if initsigs is 1. If initsigs is 0, it skips
>   initialization registration of signal handlers, which might be useful
>   when Python is embedded.

see more on its [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/init.html#c.Py_InitializeEx), and [cpython source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.3/Python/pylifecycle.c#L471-L481).

Answer (score 0):

I changed `job` function to handle `CTRL+C` interrupts:

```
    def job():
        import time
        try:    
            while True:
                print("running..")
                time.sleep(5)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print 'Exiting job..'
```

My test program is exiting cleanly after above change.

AFTER EDIT:

I added this to my C program

```
    #include<signal.h>

    void handler() {printf("Exiting main.."); exit(0);}
```

Modified `main` as:

```
    int main() {
        signal(SIGINT, handler);
```

Comment: Thank you for your experiment, but I just realized that I wrote a little wrong example for my case. I'm really sorry but I let me please change the example a bit(The infinite loop should be in the main process, not in the worker process)

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but I think that is not exactly how you make Python runtime die gracefully.