# Encrypted chat app using python and RSA algorithm

Tags: python, python-3.x, rsa, public-key-encryption, python-sockets

I am trying to create an encrypted chat application using RSA algo in python but I am getting error messages. I am unable to find the errors in the code and the chat system is not working at all. The client.py is terminating with showing this error

File "client.py", line 17, in

```
           server_string = server.recv(1024)

           OSError: [Errno 107] Transport endpoint is not connected
```

The codes are:

the server.py is:

```
import socket
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto import Random

#Generate private and public keys
random_generator = Random.new().read
private_key = RSA.generate(1024, random_generator)
public_key = private_key.publickey()

#Declartion
mysocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = socket.gethostbyname(socket.getfqdn())
port = 8888
encrypt_str = "encrypted_message="

if host == "127.0.1.1":
    import commands
    host = commands.getoutput("hostname -I")
print("host = " + host)

#Prevent socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use
mysocket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

mysocket.bind((host, port))

mysocket.listen(5)

c, addr = mysocket._accept()

while True:

    #Wait until data is received.
    data = c.recv(1024)
    data = data.replace("\r\n", '') #remove new line character

    if data == "Client: OK":
        c.send("public_key=" + public_key.exportKey() + "\n")
        print("Public key sent to client.")

    elif encrypt_str in data: #Reveive encrypted message and decrypt it.
        data = data.replace(encrypt_str, '')
        print("Received:\nEncrypted message = "+str(data))
        encrypted = eval(data)
        decrypted = private_key.decrypt(encrypted)
        c.send("Server: OK")
        print("Decrypted message = " + decrypted)

    elif data == "Quit": break

#Server to stop
c.send("Server stopped\n")
print("Server stopped")
c.close()
```

The client.py is

```
import socket
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
import sys 
import os 

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 7777

server.bind(("my_IP_addr_goes_here", 8880))
#data= "Client: OK"

#Tell server that connection is OK
#server.sendall("Client : OK")

#Receive public key string from server
server_string = server.recv(1024)

#Remove extra characters
server_string = server_string.replace("public_key=", '')
server_string = server_string.replace("\r\n", '')

#Convert string to key
server_public_key = RSA.importKey(server_string)

#Encrypt message and send to server
message = "This is my secret message."
encrypted = server_public_key.encrypt(message, 32)
server.sendall("encrypted_message="+str(encrypted))

#Server's response
server_response = server.recv(1024)
server_response = server_response.replace("\r\n", '')
if server_response == "Server: OK":
    print("Server decrypted message successfully")

#Tell server to finish connection
server.sendall("Quit")
print(server.recv(1024)) #Quit server response
server.close()
```

The errors are:
The server script is running but when I am terminating the script it's showing

For server.py: 
               ^CTraceback (most recent call last):

```
           File "server.py", line 28, in <module>

           c, addr = mysocket._accept()

           KeyboardInterrupt
```

For client.py: 
               File "client.py", line 17, in

```
           server_string = server.recv(1024)

           OSError: [Errno 107] Transport endpoint is not connected
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to capture SIGINT... See [How do I capture SIGINT in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112343/how-do-i-capture-sigint-in-python)

```
import signal
import sys
def stop_server(sig, frame):
        server.sendall("Quit")
        print(server.recv(1024)) #Quit server response
        server.close()
        sys.exit(0)
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, stop_server)
```