# closing the server after all clients are closed

Tags: python, sockets

I have a very basic socket script which sends a single message to clients.

Part of server script :

```
while True:
    con,address=s.accept()
    con.send("Hello from server".encode())
    con.close()
s.close()
```

Part of client script :

```
message = s.recv(5)
while message:
    print("Message", message.decode())
    sleep(1)
    message=s.recv(5)
s.close()
```

I start 2 clients. They both prints the message (5 bytes at a time), then close.

However the server remains open, because it is still waiting for clients.

What is the correct way to exit the server `while True` loop ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify on what condition you want your server to exit. Usually a server is programmed like a daemon, i.e., run indefinitely. In python, you already have a way to break the infinite `while` loop -- Ctrl-C to trigger a keyboard exception. Otherwise, think of the following:

1. After N clients handled, `break` inside the loop. You will need to have a counter and keep track of the clients handled
2. On some POSIX signal, such as the answer in [How do I capture SIGINT in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112343/how-do-i-capture-sigint-in-python), and usually this is the way daemons do to terminate *nicely*

By the way, your server code may need rewrite: You currently only handle one client at a time without parallel processing. It will very easy run into head-of-line blocking issues when you have many clients.