# How to break out of a loop nicely?

Tags: python

I have a program that does some work in a timed while loop like so:

```
import time
While True:
    do something
    time.sleep(60)
```

I would like to be able to break out of the loop nicely from the console and save some data on the way out. The solution I have thought of is to create a file when I want the program to quit and check for the file inside the loop like so.

```
from os.path import exists
While True:
    do something
    if exists('exit.txt'):
        print('exiting')
        clean_up()
    time.sleep(60)
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Or use setup a condition that fits your case

Comment: You can use the `break` keyword to exit a loop when a condition is met. Then, outside the `while` loop, make your call to `clean_up()`.

Comment: You're probably looking for interrupt cleanup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112343/how-do-i-capture-sigint-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put them into `try catch` statement. When you want to end the loop, exit the cycle through Ctrl+C, and then complete the work you want to finish:

```
>>> try:
...     while True: pass
... except KeyboardInterrupt:
...     print('hello')
...
[^C]
hello
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `break` keyword to exit a loop when a condition is met:

```py
from os.path import exists

while True:
    do_something()

    if exists('exit.txt'):
        print('exiting')
        break

    time.sleep(60)

clean_up()
```

As Mechanic Pig mentioned in his answer, if you want to be able to manually break out of it from the console, you could implement a KeyboardInterrupt handler:

```py
while True:
    try:
        do_something()

        if exists('exit.txt'):
            print('exiting')
            break
        
        else:
            time.sleep(60)
            continue

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('exiting')
        break

clean_up()
```