# How to stop sql excution in python

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I am trying to save big data in SQL using sqlite3 in  python, I want to test the result but no need to save all the data, if I try to press ctrl+c, I got this error: KeyboardInterrupt.
How can I stop the code without getting errors?

Comment: how are you inserting data. line by line bulk ....

Comment: Why does it matter if your interpreter acknowledges the fact that you triggered a `KeyboardInterrupt`, exactly? That's exactly what CTRL+C does...

Answer (score 0):

> How can I stop the code without getting errors?

Use a `try-catch` block:

```
try:
  ...
  # do your SQL writes here
except KeyboardInterrupt:
  # cleanup and exit the program
```

There is a [caveat](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#KeyboardInterrupt) with catching `KeyboardInterrupt`, which is very relevant in your situation:

> Catching a [`KeyboardInterrupt`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#KeyboardInterrupt) requires special consideration. Because it can be raised at unpredictable points, it may, in some circumstances, leave the running program in an inconsistent state. It is generally best to allow [`KeyboardInterrupt`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#KeyboardInterrupt) to end the program as quickly as possible or avoid raising it entirely. (See [Note on Signal Handlers and Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#handlers-and-exceptions).)

It is important to pay attention to this because you will be doing database writes and if a write is interrupted mid way, you could render your table unusable.

#### Using signal handlers instead of try-catch

An alternative (and recommended alternative) to catching the exception is to instead use a signal handler to handle the [`SIGINT`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#signal.SIGINT) signal. See [How do I capture SIGINT in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112343/how-do-i-capture-sigint-in-python)