# Proceed with default behaviour of signals

Tags: python, signals, blender

I'm running my script in [blender](https://www.blender.org/), and I want to detect `Ctrl + c` as to close the script,
but before I do close my script I want to run a function to do some cleanup

So I tried to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1112350/18005234) solution to listen for `Ctrl + c` as such:

```
import signal
import sys

def signal_handler(sig, frame):
    print('You pressed Ctrl+C!')
    sys.exit(0)

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
# insert time taking code
```

but the problem is that `sys.exit(0)` completely exists blender, whereas I need it to only stop the script execution.

So how do I invoke whatever the default behaviour of `Ctrl + c` so that that only the script stops executing?
(or am I looking in the wrong direction?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the [solution](https://blenderartists.org/t/invoke-function-before-closing-script-ctrl-c/1409269/3?u=cakelover)

```
import signal

default_handler = None

def handler(num, frame):    
    # Do something that cannot throw here (important)
    print("Hello World")

    return default_handler(num, frame) 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    default_handler = signal.getsignal(signal.SIGINT)

    # Assign the new handler
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handler)
```