# How to properly terminate a Python script running in a while loop with CTRL+C without losing connection to a remote host?

Tags: python, sockets, terminate, sigint

I am working with a Python script that runs in a infinite while loop and acquires data from a remote instrument using a socket (Remoteserver) connection over vx11. I want to be able to terminate the script gracefully using the CTRL+C command (SIGINT), which should trigger a routine to acquire the remaining data before breaking the process.

I am aware that I can handle the keyboard interrupt with `try: ... while Loop... except KeyboardInterrupt: or finally:`, or by using `signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, sigint_handle)`, but the problem I am facing is that when I use CTRL+C to terminate the script, the socket connection to the remote host gets disconnected immediately, preventing me from sending any further commands to the instrument in the acquisition routine.

Is there a way to prevent the disconnection from happening while still being able to terminate the script with `CTRL+C` and acquire the remaining data? I suspect that `CTRL+C` is being sent to all running jobs, and I would like to have a kind of discipline where only the "foreground" process is terminated first.

This is not working, the Remotehost (vx11) is broke within the first line of sigint_handler already:

```
import signal
import time
import vxi11

class Program:
    def __init__(self, ip_host):
        self.instr= vxi11.Instrument(ip_host)
        signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, self.sigint_handler)

    def run(self):
        while self.instr.ask("some commmand..") == True
            print("Running...")
            time.sleep(1)

        data = self.instr.ask("some commmand..")
        # etc. ... save data
        print("Programm end...")

    def sigint_handler(self, signum, frame):
        print("CTRL+C recieved.")
        data = self.instr.ask("some commmand..")
        # etc. ... save data
        print("Programm end...")
            

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ip_host = "1.1.1.1"  
    program = Program(ip_host)
    program.run()
```

Comment: Why do you need to keep control c as a way to gracefully close it? Control c should be used to kill it in case of an error, you could listen for some other input and terminate gracefully on that instead.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I know that real gracefully closure is done differently. But I'm integrating the script as a smaller subprocess, and in a larger parent process, other scripts are closed using subprocess.send_command(signal.SIGINT). My question was whether I can do the same with the above example, or if I need to adjust all other subprocesses as well. What would be the best termination signal, SIGTERM?

Comment: This may be able to help you in that case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112343/how-do-i-capture-sigint-in-python#1112350

Answer (score 0):

From [How do I capture SIGINT in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112343/how-do-i-capture-sigint-in-python#1112350):

```
import sys

def signal_handler(sig, frame):
    print('You pressed Ctrl+C!')
    sys.exit(0)

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
print('Press Ctrl+C')
signal.pause()
```

Using python’s signal library, you can register your own handler/listener for the interrupt signal.

Answer (score 0):

From a little playing around, it seems like the signal handler basically gets called wherever you are in the code when the signal is raised. If you try to call `ask()` from the signal handler when you were actually in an `ask()` call already, then you're making a recursive call to `ask()`, which may be why your version is failing.

You could try to set a flag value, like so:

```python
import signal
import time
from multiprocessing import Process, Event


class Program:
    def __init__(self, ip_host):
        self.instr = iter(range(20))
        self.time_to_leave = False

    def run(self):
        signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, self.sigint_handler)

        x = next(self.instr)
        while x < 10 and not self.time_to_leave:
            print("Running...", x)
            time.sleep(1)
            x = next(self.instr)

        x = next(self.instr)
        # etc. ... save data
        print("Programm end...", x)

    def sigint_handler(self, signum, frame):
        self.time_to_leave = True


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ip_host = "1.1.1.1"
    program = Program(ip_host)
    program.run()
```

If that doesn't work, you could use multiprocessing to make a child process that ignores SIGINT entirely and exits when the parent tells it to. It would look something like this:

```python
import signal
import time
from multiprocessing import Process, Event


class Program:
    def __init__(self, ip_host):
        self.instr = iter(range(20))
        self.event = Event()

    def run(self):
        # Ignore SIGINT in the child
        signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_IGN)

        x = next(self.instr)
        while x < 10 and not self.event.is_set():
            print("Running...", x)
            time.sleep(1)
            x = next(self.instr)

        x = next(self.instr)
        # etc. ... save data
        print("Programm end...", x)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ip_host = "1.1.1.1"
    program = Program(ip_host)
    process = Process(target=program.run)

    def sigint_handler(signum, frame):
        print("CTRL+C recieved.")
        program.event.set()

    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, sigint_handler)

    process.start()
    process.join()
```