# Python asyncio - prevent background task from being cancelled with ctrl-C

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I know what you're thinking - just use `asyncio.shield`. But my problem is a bit more complex. Basically, I have a `save()` function. This function is called periodically as a background task, and then it's called one final time during cleanup. This function has two requirements:

- When `save()` is called, it must wait for the previous call to `save()` to finish. This is accomplished successfully using semaphores
- The function cannot be cancelled - this is what I'm having trouble with

If I ctrl-C out of the program while a call to `save()` is active, it will cancel the task mid-save, which is bad. I've tried fixing it with `asyncio.shield`, but it isn't working. Here's a simple replica:

```
import asyncio

sem = asyncio.Semaphore(1)

async def _save():
    async with sem:
        print('saving. . . ')
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        print('done saving')

async def save():
    await asyncio.shield(_save())

async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.create_task(save())
    print('doing some other stuff. . . ')
loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
try:
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
finally:
    loop.run_until_complete(save())
```

What I want to happen when I ctrl-C out of the program is for `save()` to finish, then *save again* as part of cleanup. What actually happens is the program just ends. Any ideas as to what I'm getting wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112343/how-do-i-capture-sigint-in-python