# How to interrupt Linux kernel module without terminating the interfacing userspace process

Tags: python, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, interrupt

I've written a kernel module implementing a device driver that uses `down_interruptible` to handle access to shared resources. I have a userspace application that communicates with the kernel module. I'd like to be able to interrupt the kernel module without terminating the userspace application (this will finish on its own after the kernel module is interrupted). This can occur in one of 2 ways: (1) the userspace application knows it's time to finish and interrupts the kernel module, or (2) the user invoking the userspace application interrupts the application in which case the application should pass along the interrupt to the kernel module but otherwise ignore the interrupt. Currently, I've only been able to interrupt both the userspace application and the kernel module, or neither. I'm new to kernel module development and it could very well be that I'm going about this the wrong way. If that's the case, please feel free to mention other, better ways to do this.

Here's a minimal example that illustrates the problem I'm facing. The kernel module code is:

```c
#include <linux/cdev.h>
#include <linux/device.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/semaphore.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>
#include <linux/types.h>

#define NAME "testmod"
#define MAJOR -1

static struct class *testmod_class;
static struct cdev *testmod_cdev;
struct semaphore *lock;

static ssize_t read(struct file *filp, char __user *buf, size_t count, loff_t *f_pos)
{
    up(lock);
    printk(KERN_INFO "semaphore unlocked\n");
    printk(KERN_INFO "semaphore count: %d\n", lock->count);
    return 0;
}

static ssize_t write(struct file *filp, const char __user *buf, size_t count, loff_t *f_pos)
{
    ssize_t ret;

    if ((ret = down_interruptible(lock)) != 0) {
        printk(KERN_INFO "interrupt received\n");
    }
    printk(KERN_INFO "semaphore count: %d\n", lock->count);
    ret = count;

    return ret;
}

static const struct file_operations fops = {
    .owner = THIS_MODULE,
    .read = read,
    .write = write,
};

static int testmod_init(void)
{
    int ret;

    if ((testmod_class = class_create(NAME)) == NULL) {
        ret = -1;
        goto out;
    }

    if ((testmod_cdev = cdev_alloc()) == NULL) {
        ret = -1;
        goto cleanup_class;
    }

    testmod_cdev->ops = &fops;
    testmod_cdev->owner = THIS_MODULE;

    if (cdev_add(testmod_cdev, MAJOR, 1) == -1) {
        ret = -1;
        goto cleanup_cdev;
    }

    if ((device_create(testmod_class, NULL, MAJOR, NULL, NAME)) == NULL) {
        ret = -1;
        goto cleanup_class;
    }

    if ((lock = kzalloc(sizeof(struct semaphore), GFP_KERNEL)) == NULL) {
        ret = -1;
        goto cleanup_dev;
    }

    sema_init(lock, 1);

    ret = 0;
    goto out;

cleanup_dev:
    device_destroy(testmod_class, MAJOR);
cleanup_class:
    class_destroy(testmod_class);
cleanup_cdev:
    cdev_del(testmod_cdev);
out:
    return ret;
}

static void testmod_exit(void)
{
    device_destroy(testmod_class, MAJOR);
    class_destroy(testmod_class);
    cdev_del(testmod_cdev);
}

module_init(testmod_init);
module_exit(testmod_exit);
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

The userspace application is:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
from signal import signal, SIGINT, SIG_IGN

signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN)

fd = os.open("/dev/testmod", os.O_WRONLY)
while True:
    os.write(fd, b"1")

os.close(fd)
```

If I run the userspace application and interrupt it with ctrl-C, nothing happens, which is unsurprising since I've told it to ignore the interrupt. If I uncomment the `signal(...)` line using ctrl-C interrupts the kernel module write but also stops the userspace application.

The actual application performs these writes in threads (`threading.Thread`), though I didn't do that in this minimal example to try to keep things simple. But, if there are additional considerations when using threads, that would be good to know.

Comment: [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.write) on `os.write` clearly tells, that it automatically re-run the system call if it was interrupted by a signal without an exception. Instead of ignoring a signal, why do not handle the exception it raises? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112343/how-do-i-capture-sigint-in-python

Comment: A kernel module isn't a process. A process will be running in kernel mode and can catch signals during a system call.