How can I ensure some code is run even if a test suite is aborted?
I have a Behave test suite that starts by spinning up my application in a Docker container. I've added some code using atexit to ensure that the container is stopped and removed when the suite exits 'normally':
def handle_exit():
    context.container.stop()
    context.docker_client.close()

atexit.register(handle_exit)

This works fine as long as the test suite exits normally, even with failing tests. But sometimes the tests are aborted:
HOOK-ERROR in before_all: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/peter/Nextcloud/PycharmProjects/boardgamelibrary/boardgamelibrary'
HOOK-ERROR in after_all: AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'driver'

ABORTED: By user.

In which case the container is not cleaned up, and subsequent attempts to run the suite will fail.
Is there a stronger version of atexit that will run my handle_exit routine in all exit/abort scenarios?
To be clear, this is not a question of exception handling, or if it is, the exceptions are being handled internally by behave. There is no place for me to insert a try-catch block.

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback. It will be also more readable in question, and more people can see it - so more people may help.

if it raise error FileNotFoundError then maybe you have to put code in try / except FileNotFoundError to catch it. But if it is error in external program then it may not work because it may kill all your process and it deosn't care what you have in code. It would need to change external program.

Expanding on the exception catching idea: I wondered (without any knowledge of py behave) how all of this will be called. I'm thinking along the lines of catching SIGINT. If it's e.g. a python wrapper calling the test suite something like this might work :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112343/how-do-i-capture-sigint-in-python
